# navigation crash: unknown destination during restore

Tags: android, navigation

I have 2 navigation

A Navigation include mother fragment A and B Navigation

B Navigation include SonA fragment and SonB fragment

my flow is mother->Son A->Son B
but it crash in Son A to Son B
it show

Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.portal.login.LoginActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: unknown destination during restore: com.app.portal.dev:id/A_Navigation

why it can't restore Son A in A_Navigation ?